# Javascript:Cloud Firestore merge is replacing the data

Tags: javascript, rest, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

my initial code for writing data is this

```
var Cloud = firebase.firestore();

  Cloud.collection("IPA").doc("Allipas").set({
    IPlist: "A;B;",   
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

Then i want to merge new information into my Field

```
  var Cloud = firebase.firestore();

  Cloud.collection("IPA").doc("Allipas").set({
    IPlist: "C;",   
} , {merge : true})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

but it replaces the field with 'C' only and i cant see A & B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `merge: true` option merges the fields you provide in the API call with the existing fields in the document. It does not merge a single value with the existing value of a field.

If you want to update an existing value of a field, you will have to first read the value of that field, then update it in your code, and finally write it back to the database.

This typically is done in a transaction to ensure nobody else can write conflicting updates at the same time. An example:

```
var docRef = Cloud.collection("IPA").doc("Allipas");
Cloud.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(docRef).then(function(doc) {
        if (!doc.exists) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
        }

        var newIPlist = doc.data().IPlist + "C;";
        transaction.update(docRef, { IPList: newIPList });
    });
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
```

Note that Firebase recommends not using such composite value, or arrays, precisely for this reason: having to read the existing value before updating it reduces the scalability of your solution. Have a look at the [documentation on working with arrays, list, and sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Your merge can be change for update?

```
updteSomething() {
        this.db.collection('IPA').doc(Allipas).update({
            IPlist: ""A;B;C;",
        })
            .then(function () {
                console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: No i want to merge a new string in existing field. It is different than Update